# How to consolidate n columns to 1 row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing ~40 columns and over 150K rows that I want to consolidate into just one column. The DataFrame has `NaN` values all over the place.

Here's an example of what my `df` looks like:

```
d = {'A' : pd.Series([np.nan, 5., 3.], index=[0,1,2]),
 'B' : pd.Series([np.nan, 2., np.nan], index=[0,1,2]),
 'C' : pd.Series([1.,np.nan, 4.], index=[0,1,2])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  1.0
1  5.0  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  NaN  4.0
```

I want my resulting `df` to contain all the values from all columns, but only one column. The rows can have multiple values in multiple columns, so I need a way to keep them all like so:

```
e = {'ABC' : pd.Series([1.,5.,2.,3.,4.], index=[0,1,2,3,4])}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(e)
   ABC
0  1.0
1  5.0
2  2.0
3  3.0
4  4.0
```

The column names are all different so I haven't been able to join, merge or concatenate them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have just 1 finite value per row considering you want to have just 1 column outputted?

Comment: No, there could be 2 or more per row. The `NaN` are all over the place which is what has been making this a lot harder. I'm gonna edit my question to better show that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) seems to be a good option which automatically drops all `NaNs` by default leaving with just finite entries:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ABC': df.stack().values})
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for!